# How to calculate average from an arraylist only "calculating the positive numbers while ignoring the negatives)?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to calculate a positive average from an arraylist. It takes values from an arraylist but calculates only "positive" numbers, While testing

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[]{3, 2, -4, -7}; 
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array));
System.out.printf(averagePositive(arrayList));
```

I have tried using abs but it didn't work.

```
public static double averagePositive(ArrayList<Integer> values) {
    if (values == null || values.isEmpty())
       return 0.0;

    int sum = 0;
    int n = values.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < n  ; i++)
       if (values.get(i) > 0.0) {
           sum += values.get(i);
    }

    return ((double) sum) / n;
}
```

My desired output is 2.50 but getting 1.25

Comment: Because you divide by n instead of counting positive numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `n` is equal to the size of array. Instead it should have been count of the total positive number

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] array = new Integer[] { 3, 2, -4, -7 };
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array));
    System.out.println(averagePositive(arrayList));
}

public static double averagePositive(ArrayList<Integer> values) {
    if (values == null || values.isEmpty())
        return 0.0;

    int sum = 0;
    int n = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
        if (values.get(i) > 0.0) {
            sum += values.get(i);
            n++;
        }

    return ((double) sum) / n;
}
```

Comment: so i have to address n = 0, rather than addressing it as .size()?

Comment: yes, and increment the value of n, whenever you find a positive number because you want the average of positive elements :)

Answer (score 2):

You should count the positives and divide by that count, not by `n`:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n  ; i++) {
    if (values.get(i) > 0.0) {
        sum += values.get(i);
        count++;
    }
}
if (count > 0) {
    return ((double) sum) / count;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. The only part you're missing is that you want to take avg of positive elements, so total amount of elements should be 2 in your case. You should count only positive elements, like this:

```
int n = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n  ; i++)
   if (values.get(i) > 0.0) {
       sum += values.get(i);
       n++;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide the sum with the number of positive elements, not the total size.

```
public static double averagePositive(ArrayList<Integer> values) {
if (values == null || values.isEmpty())
   return 0.0;

int sum = 0;
int positive_n = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n  ; i++)
   if (values.get(i) > 0.0) {
       sum += values.get(i);
         positive_n++;
}

return ((double) sum) / positive_n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should count how many positive values you have instead on dividing by the list size:

```
int positiveCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n  ; i++)
       if (values.get(i) > 0.0) {
           sum += values.get(i);
           positiveCount++;
}

return ((double) sum) / positiveCount;
```

Or you can use Streams:

```
public static double averagePositive(List<Integer> values) {
    return values.stream()
                 .filter(d -> d > 0.0)
                 .mapToDouble(Function.identity())
                 .average().orElse(0.0);
}
```